# CSS Selector to select first and second table cells

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me figure what selectors I need to change the width of my columns globally on my two column table?

Using this, will of course select all cells:

```
table td {
    width: 50px;
}
```

What I want is this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px">data in first column</td>
        <td style="width: 180px">data in second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px">more data in first column</td>
        <td style="width: 180px">more data in second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to put the width specification in a style sheet rather then typing the width implicitly for each  tag. What CSS selector will let me set the 50px width and 180px appropriately?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yep.

```
td:first-child{
   width:50px;
}

td:nth-child(2){
   width: 180px;
}
```

or, as suggested by Brainslav's edit:

```
td:nth-child(1) {
      width: 50px;}
td:nth-child(2) {
      width: 180px;}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/QmMz4/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `class` names in your markup and utilizing `colgroup`. It's by far the least hassle since you define the width only in `colgroup`, and is cross-browser compatible.

Eg.

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="colOne" />
        <col class="colTwo" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>data in first column</td>
        <td>data in second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>more data in first column</td>
        <td>more data in second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>

/* CSS */

.colOne{
    width: 50px;
}
.colTwo{
    width: 180px;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ebnE/

One thing though, `colgroup` is deprecated in HTML5. But then again HTML5 isn't standardized yet, so you can make the call.

Oh, and it's possible to do without any CSS if you fancy:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="50"/>
        <col width="180" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>data in first column</td>
        <td>data in second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>more data in first column</td>
        <td>more data in second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer! Even better, `colgroup` is not deprecated in [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-colgroup-element).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use css pseudo-selectors:

```
table tr td:first-child {
    width: 50px;
}
table tr td:last-child {
    width: 150px;
}
td {
    background: gray;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data in first column</td>
        <td>data in second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>more data in first column</td>
        <td>more data in second column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's an example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scottm28/gGXy6/11/

Alternatively, you could also use [CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)